# Plotting discrete piecewise function - signal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I need to plot a discrete signal that is defined by a piecewise function :

```
if n < 0 , x = (135/56) * (0.9)^n - (1/8)(0.1)^n - (2/7)(0.2)^n  

if 0<=n< 4, x = (135/56) * (0.9)^n + (7/8)(0.1)^n + (5/7)(0.2)^n  

if n>=4 , x = (135/56) * (0.9)^n + (7/8)(0.1)^n + (5/7)(0.2)^n + (0.1)^(-4) + (0.2)^(-4)
```

I have searched a lot in web and especially here and I came up with this code , that after many corrections it actually runned in spyder. But the result is definetely not the expected one. Can anyone help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xPoints = []
nPoints = []
q = (135 / 56)
z= -(1/8)
r = -(2/7)
m = 7/8
p = 5 /7
j = np.power(0.1, -3.5)
a = np.power(0.2, -3.5)
for n in range(-5,11):
    if n<0 :
        x = q *np.power(0.9, n) + z* np.power(0.1, n) + r* np.power(0.2, n)
    elif (n>=0 and n<4):
        x =q *np.power(0.9, n) + m* np.power(0.1, n) + p* np.power(0.2, n)
    else:
        x =q *np.power(0.9, n) + m* np.power(0.1, n) + p* np.power(0.2, n)+ j + a
    xPoints.append(x)
    nPoints.append(n)
plt.plot(nPoints, xPoints)
plt.plot.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the output wrong? How do you know, it is wrong?

Comment: I know it's wrong because with a calculator, and by hand I calculated some values and they do not match

Comment: Like what value? -2? 4? 1.3?

Comment: yes, for instance for `n=0` , `x[n] = 4` , for `n=-4`, x[-4]=0 et.c, but the obvious problem with the result it is that it is continuous

Comment: `x[0]` is 4, but why would `x[-4]` be 0? `x[-1]` is 0.

Comment: Is your question solved now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy stepwise functions can be created using [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). One of numpy's most magical features is [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), where a function can be called on a complete array of values at once.

Your example code creates the expected curve, but only adds a point at integer values. To create a smooth curve, [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) creates a long array of values (the code below uses 1000 little steps between -5 and 5). (Note that numpy needs the [`&` operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations) for a logical `and` of two array expressions. In this particular case you could use `n < 4` instead of `(n >= 0) & (n < 4)` as the case of `n < 0` is taken care of earlier.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = (135 / 56)
z = -(1 / 8)
r = -(2 / 7)
m = 7 / 8
p = 5 / 7
j = np.power(0.1, -3.5)
a = np.power(0.2, -3.5)

n = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
x = np.where(n < 0, q * np.power(0.9, n) + z * np.power(0.1, n) + r * np.power(0.2, n),
             np.where((n >= 0) & (n < 4), q * np.power(0.9, n) + m * np.power(0.1, n) + p * np.power(0.2, n),
                      q * np.power(0.9, n) + m * np.power(0.1, n) + p * np.power(0.2, n) + j + a))
plt.plot(n, x)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

If you only want the integer positions, you can use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) instead of `np.linspace` and then create a scatter plot (`plt.scatter(n, x)`) or maybe a [stemplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = (135 / 56)
z = -(1 / 8)
r = -(2 / 7)
m = 7 / 8
p = 5 / 7
j = np.power(0.1, -3.5)
a = np.power(0.2, -3.5)

n = np.arange(-5, 6)
x = np.where(n < 0, q * np.power(0.9, n) + z * np.power(0.1, n) + r * np.power(0.2, n),
             np.where((n >= 0) & (n < 4), q * np.power(0.9, n) + m * np.power(0.1, n) + p * np.power(0.2, n),
                      q * np.power(0.9, n) + m * np.power(0.1, n) + p * np.power(0.2, n) + j + a))
plt.stem(n, x)
plt.show()
```

[image: example stem plot]

Comment: the problem is this can't be the right plot, because first of all it is continuous , we need a discrete one, that;s why I am concerned about my result

Comment: It seems, you are looking for [`plt.step(n, x, where="post")`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html). Or maybe even just [`plt.scatter(n, x)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).